# Python: Novice Class object prac and __main__

Tags: python

I've been trying to practice testing my modules by adding

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

to the end of the module. The idea is to run the module as a script, and get an output
and able to import it from another script or an interactive python session.

I'm using Python 2.6.6

here's the whole code

```
class Prac:
    '''
    This module is a practice in creating a main within a module.
    '''

    def Fun(self):
        print "testing function call"


if __name__ == ' __main__':
    Fun()
```

Comment: thanks Ignacio....duh...forgot to instantiate the object. Will try again and post

Comment: what exactly is the qeustion this time?

Comment: Ok, it looks like you have working code... did you have a question to go with that?

Comment: I was confusing import of the file containing the class object and the obj themselves...Now I can get good output from interactive python, but the __main__ is not working calling from bash $.

Comment: There seems to be more missing from this than just the question itself. You go on to talk about issues you were having in the interactive session with the TypeError when trying to call the module as a callable. What is your entire process that you are leaving out of this post?

Comment: I think the reason everyone hates this question has partly to do with: It's a novice question, so it has more than one fault to fix.I tried to edit the original code to reflect to actual question asked, but it was rolled back, Which was a mistake because my question is: how so I use the if __name__ == '__main__': to test a module. First I had to fix a misunderstanding with my syntax for calling a method from the module.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a function, it's a method. You need to call the method off an object.

```
p = Prac()
p.Fun()
```

[Read this.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: I tried calling the method from an interactive session, but got TypeError: 'module' object is not callable